# How to pass an element into a setTimeOut function

Tags: javascript

I am getting an **element** and I want to apply a click function to it with a delay. I am, however, unsure how to pass the element into the click function.

**This is what I have:**

```
var element = document.querySelector(".some-element");

setTimeout(function(element) {
    element.click();
}, 200);
```

Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"

What is the correct way to do this?

NOTE:
This works as expected without the setTimeout method.

Comment: Remove `element` from the function parameters and it will work. You are not passing anything to the function (because you are not calling the function). The function closes over the scope where `element` is defined (it's a closure). You are getting the error because the code that *actually* calls the function does not pass an argument to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".some-element");

setTimeout(function() {
     element.click();
}, 200);
```

You are referring the element not the variable but the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `setTimeout` function you're adding a param named `element`, so `element` inside that function is not the same as element declared before. 
Remove element as param like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    element.click();
}, 200);
```